Can a quadratic equation whose discriminant is less than 0 can be written as a sum of squares of monomial?
Suppose we have a quadratic equation,
$$
ax^2+bx+c\quad\mbox{with}\quad b^2-4ac<0.
$$
Does there exists real numbers $A,B,C,D$ such that
\begin{align}
AD-BC & =1
\\[1mm] \mbox{and}\quad ax^2+bx+c & =(Ax-B)^2+(Cx-D)^2\ ?.
\end{align}

I have shown that this is possible only if $b^2-4ac=-4$.
But I still have a doubt on my proof.
I have a doubt in my proof because the existence of such real numbers $A,B,C,D$ was used in the proof of a lemma in a paper authored by a
renowned mathematician without assuming that $b^2-4ac=-4$.

Can anyone please help me ?.

Please include your proof and the lemma by the "renowned mathematician". This will help people avoid duplicating your (or their) effort. Moreover, someone may be able to verify (or refute) your proof directly without having to start from scratch. ... Good luck!

I come to the same conclusion as you, that $b^2-4ac=-4$, but perhaps there is some other reason the paper could do what it did; that would be something we could look at.

When $AD-BC = 1$  and
$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
A & -C \\ 
-B & D \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
A & -B \\ 
-C & D \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
a & \frac{b}{2} \\ 
\frac{b}{2} & c \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
then the determinant $ac - \frac{b^2}{4} = 1$
